# How to capture back to back images using Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I have written a program, in which i am allowing user to **capture an image**, but once user capture an image i am **not able to open camera** again same time to allow user to capture more photos getting previous camera screen, to capture number of pics user has to close and then again need to open an app.

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @ChintanRathod i have posted my code please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write following code after saving your image in `PictureCallBack`

```
camera.startPreview();
```

This will start preview of camera after taking picture.